How do i fix a Cart error with payments?
Whenever someone tries to buy a product on my website it stops the payment and gives and error, which i searched in the logs and this is what i've found:
main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-672e2e0e06cfd; Message: Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress' {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-672e2e0e06cfd; Message: Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress' at /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, Zend_Validate_Exception(code: 0): Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress' at /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Validate.php:244)"}

The issue face with specific payment method only? Or for all?
